# Jar file does not find sqlite data base path

Tags: java, path, database-connection

I'm working on javaFx project ,I have a problem that when i run my project in netbeans every thing is well but when i run my jar file by using cmd i find this error :[image]

This my part of code to connect to database :

```
package Connection;

import java.sql.*;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;

/**
 *
 * @author Ala_Eddine
 */
public class Dbaconnection {

    private static Connection connection;

    public Dbaconnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
            config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/DataBase/Beans/sqllite/Model/Data.db",config.toProperties());
            System.out.println("Connection accepted" + connection);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (connection == null) {
            Dbaconnection dbaconnection = new Dbaconnection();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        getConnection();

    }

}
```

And this is a location of database file :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem if you are trying to embed your database inside the `.jar` file. You can try the following:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:path/to/your/database.db")
```

So when everything is packaged, you will be able to connect.

Comment: Thank you it is worked correct by changing `"jdbc:sqlite:src/DataBase/Beans/sqllite/Model/Data.db"` to `"jdbc:sqlite::resource:DataBase/Beans/sqllite/Model/Data.db‌​"`